# Stacking menus on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have a fixed nav div following your scroll on top of the page. I would also want a second menu div to stack on collision with this first div when scrolling down a bit.
To be more precise, this second menu stays on the normal flow until it collides with the fixed one when scrolling down, then I would want this second div to stay fixed there for the rest of the scrolling like in the image.

How would I do that?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a jQuery plugin you may want to look into: http://stickyjs.com/

Comment: This even lets you customize a new style for the menu on collision detect. Works great! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple jquery for this. Try this demo http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/8MZe5/2/

```
<header class="header">
    your header goes here...
</header>
<section class="mainContent">
    <div class="lftCol">
        <div class="lftColContent">This is Left column</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rhtCol">
        This is Right column
    </div>
</section>

html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #f4f4f4;
}
.mainContent{
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.lftCol{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
.lftColContent{
     width: 80px;
     background: red;
}
.rhtCol{
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: blue;
}

var hdrHeight = $(".header").outerHeight();
var mainCnt = $(".mainContent");
var lftSticky = $(".lftColContent");

$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > hdrHeight) {        
            lftSticky.css({
                "position":"fixed",
                "top": hdrHeight
            });
            return false;
        }
        else {
            lftSticky.css({
                "position":"static",
                "top": 0
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```